# boost::asio and idle processor

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I need a sort of an idle processor in `boost::asio`.
A callback that is invoked within `io_sevice::run()` when all the async events have been handled.

There’s a way to register a deferred method call, `io_service::post()`, but this invokes the specified callback directly on the next processing loop, without checking if there are events on sockets.

Is there a way to achieve this with `boost::asio`?

Comment: might just be able run the `io_context` without a `work_guard` then call `run` in a loop, each time `run` returns there aren't any outstanding events

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT/UPDATE

My main idea is to use a `poll_one()` loop (instead of `run()`) that also polls your idle work.

```
while (!io_service.stopped()) {
   if (!io_service.poll_one())
      run_idle_work();
}
```

You can achieve better integration with Asio generalizing a bit to "prioritized handlers" like in this example: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/invocation/prioritised_handlers.cpp. Here all the handlers are also posted to a priority-queue:

```
  while (io_service.run_one())
  {
    // The custom invocation hook adds the handlers to the priority queue
    // rather than executing them from within the poll_one() call.
    while (io_service.poll_one())
      ;

    pri_queue.execute_all();
  }
```

There's also a more complicated, more modern scheduler/executor based approach usin c++14: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp14/executors/priority_scheduler.cpp

---

<strike>What you are looking for is work guards.</strike>

The best way is to use

```
asio::io_context io;
auto work = make_work_guard(io);
```

You can then, when you want to allow the service thread(s) to complete, reset it:

```
work.reset();
```

Note that work-guards actually track work on *executors*, so the above is equivalent to

```
asio::io_context io;
asio::executor_work_guard<asio::io_context::executor_type>
     work = make_work_guard(io.get_executor());
```

This makes it easy for you to write execution-context agnostic code:

```
template <typename AsyncReadStream>
void foo(AsyncReadStream& s) {
     auto w = make_work_guard(s.get_executor());
}
```

Which will work regardless of whether `s` uses `io_context::executor_type`, `thread_pool::executor_type` or `system_executor`.

> Note that by default `asio::ip::tcp::socket` and friends use the type erased `asio::any_io_executor` type

Comment: this stops the `io_context` from running out of work and stopping, it doesn't provide a callback for when there is no work to execute

Comment: @AlanBirtles I may have misread the question. To be **notified** when all handlers have completed you can make your own executor type that adds the functionality; https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/model/executors.html (e.g. [`on_work_finished`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/Executor1.html#boost_asio.reference.Executor1.standard_executors))

Comment: @AlanBirtles After giving it some thought and scanning the examples I updated the answer.